# groupby - somar segundo criterios

Tags: pandas

Eu pretendo somar todos os ganhos de um funcionario, pelo seu cpf, mas apenas quando ele ganhar 100, desconsiderando outros valores. Eu estou usando esse codigo, mas nao da certo:

```
aip.groupby(['CPF']).sum() where(aip['Valor']==100)
```

Tirando a coluna soma, que soma tudo, e não apenas na ocorrência de 100,00, o modelo de planilha q to trabalhando eh igual a esse:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/psofy.jpg

Mas nao quero que some tudo, e sim somente no caso em que a comissão for máxima, ou seja, 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Questão

Olá Roger, para resolver é simples, a gente só tem que pensar na lógica de encadeamento do pandas para executar de forma correta. Se você quer somar (totalizar), os CPFs (agregados) com valores superiores a 100 então: Primeiro você filtra os valores, depois agrupa os CPFs e por fim, soma.

#### Exemplo

**Importamos as bibliotecas e criamos o dataframe**

Geramos 300 valores randomicamente de 1 a 500 para os dados e de 1 a 4 para o CPF.

```
# importa as bibliotecas
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# cria o dataframe do exemplo
data = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1, 501, size=300), name='Dados')
cpf = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1, 5, size=300), name='CPF')
df = pd.concat([data, cpf], axis=1)
```

**Saída de df**

```
    Dados   CPF
0   424     4
1   416     1
2   231     1
3   423     1
4   36      1
5   14      4
6   317     1
7   4       4
8   34      3
9   98      1
10  464     4
...
```

**Resolução do problema**

Como já citado, para resolver basta: 1. filtrar os dados; 2. agrupá-los pela coluna desejada; 3. somar. Outras operações podem ser realizadas como: contar (count) ou média (mean).

```
df[df['Dados'] > 100].groupby(['CPF']).sum()
```

**Saída**

```
CPF Dados
1   19023
2   17130
3   16998
4   16309
```

Para resolver qualquer outro problema futuro utilizando pandas, pense em como criar um pipeline (encadeamento) de operações lógicas mais adequadas para isso. Requer treino, mas você pega o jeito. Abraço e bons estudos.